# Determine external keys present

Tags: android, android-keypad

Is there a way to check programatically what are the external keys present on my android device (eg volume keys , Power keys , Menu key). Different devices might have different external keys hence wanted to know if there is a way to determine the external keys present on a device. If thats not possible are there different API's to determine if the device has a external Volume up / Down key , Power key, Camera key

Answer (score 0):

For most of your hardware features/sensors you can find useful constants in the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class.

Specifically for a hardware menu key, you would need to use the [ViewConfiguration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey%28%29) class and it's *hasPermanentMenuKey()* method.

And I haven't been able to find anything on detecting hardware volume keys..

Answer (score -1):

Yep, it's pretty easy actually... here's some code to determine if the keys are present:

```
boolean hasCameraKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA);
boolean hasVolumeKeys = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
                        && KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN);
```

Comment: I found this unreliable. I have a device which only has a power button, F1 button and back button but deviceHasKey(KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) returns true...